# Start magnolia's project archetype from official catalog

Tags: maven, magnolia

**Scenario 1**

I am following the steps described in the [official documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Creating+a+custom+bundle#Creatingacustombundle-Createanemptyproject), so that

- I select the magnolia-project-archetype, version 1.2.2 from the [public catalog](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/)
- Project structure matches that of the screenshot in the docs, eclipse gives no hints of errors present.

  - [image]
- The maven clean install build is successful.
- After adding the webapp to a tomcat server, it starts up fine, no ERROR in console.

The problem is that whether I try with default context root (xyz-webapp), or modify it to /, still http://localhost:8080/ gives 404 error but after the docs I should be getting to the install page. What am I doing wrong?

---

I'm using

- pom.xml: Magnolia version 5.6 and java version 1.8
- System env.: Win10, tomcat 8.0.50 with jre 1.8.0_161, mvn 3.5.2, eclipse oxygen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this old but [official screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aU7q3daQ8S0) which is doing exactly what I'm after. In the first scenario, presented in the question I added the maven archetype modules from Eclipse. Now I followed the video, so I used only mvn to set up the project with:

- `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/`
- cd to base dir
- mvn clean install
- cd to webapp dir
- `mvn war:inplace`
- delete xyz-webapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib

Now after importing this to Eclipse there were some things to resolve

- `error unpacking magnolia-empty-webapp-5.6.war` I tried to run maven update few times, not sure if this resolved it but I don't get this anymore.
- warnings like groupId is defined in parent, no need for it in modules, so removed them.
- xml errors from jackrabit-*.xml files with "Referenced files contains errors". I don't know how to resolve these, left them as they are.
- The file cannot be validated as the XML definition `"...\templateModule\src\main\resources\META-INF\magnolia\module.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)" that is specified as describing the syntax of the file cannot be located.    templateModule.xml /templateModule/src/main/resources/META-INF/magnolia line 2  XML Problem`

  - line 2: `<!DOCTYPE module SYSTEM "module.dtd" >`
- When running the server now I get at least an error:

  - `ERROR info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener : Oops, Magnolia could not be started
    info.magnolia.module.model.reader.ModuleDependencyException: The following exceptions were found while checking Magnolia modules dependencies (i.e. those in META-INF/magnolia/my-module.xml):
    Module Magnolia Admincentral (version 5.6.0) is dependent on imaging (version 3.4/*), which was not found.`
  - So I added the dependency magnolia-imaging in `/templateModule/pom.xml`

Now it starts up as expected.